# Display portrait-oriented iPad App on TV screen via HDMI

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on an iPad App. I'd like to get my TV, which is rotated to 90 degrees so that it's effectively a 'portrait' display, to display the iPad screen app as shown below. I want the iPad app to be in portrait orientation and display its screen on the TV which is also oriented as a portrait.

[image]

They are connected via HDMI. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082434/presenting-ipad-app-on-external-portrait-tv). Just edit your earlier question.

Comment: Please list any attempted solutions and, what didn't work.

Comment: I have two TVs, one is in landscape and one is in portrait. If i open my iPad app in landscape TV it looks fine but when i open my app in portrait TV, app behaves side ways.